# Feature Idea: Points for Trying

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

I just asked what turned out to be a surprisingly vicious question about regular expressions.

Two guys were working on it, and the guy who got it definitely got some inspiration from the guy who didn't as they iteratively approached a solution.

In a case like this I would like to be able to give the other guy who also worked hard some points, but there is essentially no way to do it. It would be nice if--maybe as a privilege after a certain point level--you were able to reward a few points to someone else without constraint (doesn't have to be a huge number maybe 5 per month or something, this has only happened to me twice and I've asked a lot of questions) but it might encourage people who know think they aren't going to be fast enough to try to answer some questions anyway.

Comment: Commotion and no [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067958/regular-exp-in-eclipse-find-and-replace-match-everything-between-curly-braces)? That's just teasing...

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067958/regular-exp-in-eclipse-find-and-replace-match-everything-between-curly-braces

Comment: I upvoted both.  Problem solved.

Comment: This isn't kindergarten. You don't always get points for trying. If the answers were helpful, upvote them. If not, and the person isn't interested in working with you to update their answer to the actual solution, then do nothing at all.

Answer (score 32):

Why don't you just upvote him/her? It is how it works, if you like it, or when it helped you just upvote his/her answer.

Comment: yeah, but what if his answer is just not as good, still though I guess you're right.

Comment: @tjb: it doesn't matter. It helped you and that's the main point

Comment: You can upvote more than one answer, @tjb. Upvotes _are_ "points for trying". That's **precisely** what they are.

Answer (score 11):

Beside upvoting his answer, you may offer him a bounty :-) (but that's expensive, minimum is 50)

Comment: This is the correct way to "tip" someone above and beyond a vote or accepted answer.